# Java exception connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, connection

SOLVED
The latest version of MySQL JDBC driver evidently attempts to create an SSL connection. The app which WORKED did NOT define javax.net.ssl.keystore (and other) values, so (I assume) it reverts to a non-SSL connection. The app which FAILED did define all of the keystore/certificate parameters and then the connection attempt failed - still not sure of exactly why, if someone could enlighten would appreciate. The exception thrown could also be more informative.

Anyway, adding "&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" to the connection parameters works for both applications. (Although not a very good setup for any production app, can use for this POC!)

============= Original Posting Follows =========

This has had me stumped for a few days! AWS server (86_64), Fedora 29, Java 8 (1.8.0_201-b09), MySQL - all upgraded to the latest release. MySQL is running on the same server. Driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Connection params: jdbc:mysql://172.31.10.222:3306?user=xxxx&password=xxxx. (IP is the AWS private IP for this server.)

Have 2 different utilities - separate 'main' routines, but all in the same JAR file. The first one works perfectly, the second one aborts with the stack pasted below. This is consistent over dozens of trials with minor variations.

The different main routines both use the 'connectToDB' method shown in the stack trace. Instrumented this to log all parameters and the class name of the driver in both cases and verified that they are identical.

Have already tried/verified:

- Multiple Google searches of the same error
- MySql is running and OK (connect thru another terminal window w no problem),
- Same JAR used with all local code
- Classpath is identical
- Running under the same Linux user, using the same MySQL user/password
- Verified the IP above (172.31.10.222)
- Also changed the IP to 'localhost', 127.0.0.1, and a symbolic name from /etc/hosts
- Added -Xmx2G to make sure not an OOM issue

These are 2 different 'main' methods, but don't do much more than load some properties (from the same property files) before trying to connect to the DB. Then they execute the same connectToDB routine.

Something in the context must be different! Hoping that someone here can at least provide some hints on where to look!

Thanks

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
        at spc.tools.spcConnection.connectToDB(spcConnection.java:692)
        at spc.tools.spcConnection.connectToLocalDB(spcConnection.java:1418)
        at spc.tools.spcConnection.loadAllConnectionsOK(spcConnection.java:1112)
        at spc.tools.spcConnection.initOneTime(spcConnection.java:1012)
        at spc.tools.spcConnection.init(spcConnection.java:194)
        at spc.ops.spcServerBase.environmentOK(spcServerBase.java:367)
        at spc.ops.spcServerBase.environmentOK(spcServerBase.java:342)
        at spc.run.daemon.spcDaemon.main(spcDaemon.java:1082)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:351)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1442)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:720)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1144)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1280)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1190)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:369)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:315)
```

====================================================== New Information =====

Here are the key lines from the connectToDB method (responding to comment below):

```
Driver dvr = (Driver)Class.forName(info.sDBDriver).newInstance();
if(dvr!=null) conn = dvr.connect(accessString(), null);
```

verified the expected driver and that accessString() returns the 'jdbc:mysql:...' string as above. The exception is thrown executing the 2nd line above.

Since the original post, put in code to run a 'netstat -ln' immediately before these lines and post the result to the log. This shows an active listener for port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can post connectToDB() method.

According to this sentence " The first one works perfectly, the second one aborts with the stack pasted below.", you must have closed the db connection in the first connectToDB() call.

So that second call is broken as the DB connection was terminated by first call.

The good way to setup is to use dependency injection for database object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Updated the original post with some new information, including the key lines from connectToDB(). Re the "first one works perfectly" -- these are two completely independent processes (with separate 'main' methods) so the 2nd process creates a new connection completely.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.
You may need to close/terminate the connection of the first call. Then you can create a new instance of the driver 

The problem could be that the first driver connection with the database is still going on when the second one tried to connect the database so that database reject the connection.